# ‘seewave' install error “'sndfile.h' file not found” (for R 3.2.0 under OSX Yosemite)

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, libsndfile

When updating to R 3.2.0 I had to reinstall `seewave`.

I managed to install the required packages `fftw`, `tuneR`, `rgl`, and `rpanel`.

But, when trying to  compile `seewave` I got the message:

```
stft.c:3:11: fatal error: 'sndfile.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 22):

On linux it is sufficient to install libsndfile library, for example with

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
```

On OS X just do:

```
brew install libsndfile
```

Comment: Thanks user44509, As OSX doesn't include Aptitude, I searched for something similar and installed Homebrew and "brew install libsndfile" did the job.

Comment: Updated solution: on macOS 10.13, installing `seewave` 2.1, I had to install both **libsndfile** and **fftw** with Homebrew: `brew install libsndfile fftw`

Answer (score 0):

Pisca46 - Installing via 'brew install libsndfile' helped.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS, the package has a different name :

```
sudo yum install libsndfile-devel
```

I also had to install the fftw-devel yum package