# seewave install error “'sndfile.h' file not found"

Tags: r, terminal, compiler-errors, package, installation

I've just upgraded to R 3.4.0 and needed to reinstall all R packages. However, if I run `install.packages('seewave')`, I get this error:

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘seewave’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘seewave’

trying URL 'https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/src/contrib/seewave_2.0.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2492482 bytes (2.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘seewave’ ...
** package ‘seewave’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c stft.c -o stft.o
stft.c:3:11: fatal error: 'sndfile.h' file not found
# include <sndfile.h> //Library for write or read sound file
          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [stft.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘seewave’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/seewave’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/5v/mwpxjb1n6qzfqp9l9t99bbl80000gn/T/Rtmpx5i071/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("seewave") :
  installation of package ‘seewave’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] readxl_1.0.0    mapview_2.0.1   leaflet_1.1.0   tidyr_0.6.3     cowplot_0.7.0   GGally_1.3.0    geosphere_1.5-5
 [8] broom_0.4.2     testthat_1.0.2  english_1.1-2   dplyr_0.5.0     scales_0.4.1    stargazer_5.2   combinat_0.0-8 
[15] extrafont_0.17  car_2.1-4       raster_2.5-8    maptools_0.9-2  ggmap_2.6.1     ggplot2_2.2.1   rgdal_1.2-7    
[22] rgeos_0.3-23    sp_1.2-4        knitr_1.16      lubridate_1.6.0 stringr_1.2.0   plyr_1.8.4      reshape2_1.4.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] maps_3.1.1         viridisLite_0.2.0  foreach_1.4.3      splines_3.4.0      R.utils_2.5.0      shiny_1.0.3       
 [7] assertthat_0.2.0   stats4_3.4.0       cellranger_1.1.0   Rttf2pt1_1.3.4     lattice_0.20-35    quantreg_5.33     
[13] extrafontdb_1.0    digest_0.6.12      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 minqa_1.2.4        colorspace_1.3-2   R.oo_1.21.0       
[19] htmltools_0.3.6    httpuv_1.3.3       Matrix_1.2-9       psych_1.7.5        SparseM_1.77       xtable_1.8-2      
[25] webshot_0.4.0      satellite_0.2.0    jpeg_0.1-8         lme4_1.1-13        MatrixModels_0.4-1 tibble_1.3.1      
[31] mgcv_1.8-17        nnet_7.3-12        lazyeval_0.2.0     gdalUtils_2.0.1.7  pbkrtest_0.4-7     mnormt_1.5-5      
[37] proto_1.0.0        magrittr_1.5       crayon_1.3.2       mime_0.5           R.methodsS3_1.7.1  nlme_3.1-131      
[43] MASS_7.3-47        foreign_0.8-67     tools_3.4.0        RgoogleMaps_1.4.1  munsell_0.4.3      compiler_3.4.0    
[49] rlang_0.1.1        units_0.4-4        nloptr_1.0.4       iterators_1.0.8    rjson_0.2.15       htmlwidgets_0.8   
[55] crosstalk_1.0.0    base64enc_0.1-3    codetools_0.2-15   gtable_0.2.0       DBI_0.6-1          reshape_0.8.6     
[61] R6_2.2.1           udunits2_0.13      stringi_1.1.5      parallel_3.4.0     Rcpp_0.12.10       sf_0.4-3          
[67] mapproj_1.2-4      png_0.1-7
```

Note that this question has been asked before here: [‘seewave' install error “'sndfile.h' file not found” (for R 3.2.0 under OSX Yosemite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219360/seewave-install-error-sndfile-h-file-not-found-for-r-3-2-0-under-osx-yose)

I ran the various bit of code in this answer in Terminal, but none seemed to work. A screenshot is below:

[image]

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Since you're on MacOS using Homebrew (and therefore the `brew install` command) would be the easiest - but it looks like either you haven't installed Homebrew or it got installed incorrectly (or it hasn't been added to your path correctly)

Comment: Install homebrew correctly and the `brew` command should work. `apt-get` and `yum` are package managers for Linux distributions, so they won't work on OS X.

Comment: I ran `brew install` in Terminal and this was output: `/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0`. Do you know what I need to do now?

Comment: Have you actually installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)?