# Can't install package in maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to work with some audio analysis and want to use the Phash perceptual algorithm. [Here's a Java implementation I want to use](https://github.com/starkdg/JPhashAudio).

I'm having trouble adding this project as a dependency; I don't see how to run `mvn package test install` to get this project linked.

Similarly, this project needs [this other project](https://github.com/starkdg/libAudioData) to read the audio files. When I try to install the library using the `cmake` commands I get errors like `sndfile.h: No such file or directory`. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980601) shows how to install it, but I still get the `sndfile.h: No such file or directory` error. I'm on a Mac, by the way. I found the `sndfile.h` file and copied it to the directory, but the build didn't work in the end anyway.

I feel like this isn't the right way to do this and things should "work" after doing the basic install commands listed in the repositories. What am I missing?

Comment: The question does not really tell us what exact problems you encountered. For Maven: You take a Maven project, then you run `mvn clean install` on it (of course, first install Maven and add it to the PATH). Then it is available on your account in your local repository, so other Maven projects can use it as `<dependency>`.

Comment: As @JFMeier mentioned, configure `maven` and do a `mvn clean install`. It will update your local `m2` repository with the artifact. Then you can use this as a dependency in your project's pom by adding the following. `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.phash.phashaudio</groupId>
            <artifactId>JPHashAudio</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>`